# Pass native query per parameter to JpaRepository Interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I need to create an interface that extends the JpaRepository where I want to pass a native (select) `query` by parameter instead of leaving static within the `@Query` annotation. Instead of using `@Query (value = "select * from a where a =: a", nativeQuery = true)` I want to use the code sampled below.

```java
 public interface MeuRepository extends JpaRepository<MeuEntity, Integer>{

     @Query(value = query, nativeQuery = true)
     List<MeuEntity> findCustomNativeQuery(String query);
 }
```

Is it possible to do as the code exemplified above?
How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you MUST use native queries then do it with custom implementation.

```
public interface  MeuRepositoryCustom {
  List<MeuEntity> findCustomNativeQuery(String query);
}
```

then

```
public class  MeuRepositoryImpl implements  MeuRepositoryCustom{

@PeristenceContext
private EntityManager em; // here you will get plain EntityManager impl.

List<MeuEntity> findCustomNativeQuery(String query){

 TypedQuery<MeuEntity> q=em.createQuery(query,MeuEntity.class)
 return q.getResultList();
}
}
```

finally your repository interface

```
public interface MeuRepository extends JpaRepository<MeuEntity, Integer>, MCustomRepository{

 }
```

Notice that naming is crucial here, as custom interface has to be named `***Custom` and its implementation has to be `***Impl`

For more information https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html point 1.3

Here is newer version of documentation

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Comment: I need to create one `***Custom` and `***Impl` for all my repositories?

Comment: The whole idea of Spring data is to get away from creating custom plain queries, and as you want to go back, then yes. Threat it as backward compatible mechanism ;) But you can always make your custom interface generic right and make all repositories extend it.

Comment: I need to customize the `where` so I pass a `Map<Key, String>` and dynamically build the `where` to compose the `select`.
understand?

Comment: Yep, I would use `CriteriaQuery` for that, and looks like that is the only option here, to do it in custom repo implementation. If you have complex criteria like this, this is the way to go .

Comment: I do not know how to do this, I needed a step by step

Comment: LIke in answer https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations - step by step

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I ended up discovering and implementing the link tutorial [link](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-adding-custom-methods-into-all-repositories/)

Comment: @BrunoNogueiraSilva np Im glad I could help.